# Why do I keep getting cannot find symbol method errors in my code?

Tags: java

I'm working on this Zuul Game for class and I have to refactor the currentRoom variable into the Player class from the Game class.  I'm pretty confident with most of the code, but the Cannot Find Symbol - Method error keeps coming up when I try to compile.  Please help.

Here is the Game class:

```
class Game {
    private Parser parser;
    private Scenario scenario;

    /**
     * Create the game and initialise its internal map.
     */
    public Game() {
        scenario = new Scenario();
        parser = new Parser();
    }

    /**
     *  Main play routine.  Loops until end of play.
     */
    public void play() {
        printWelcome();

        // Enter the main command loop.  Here we repeatedly read commands and
        // execute them until the game is over.

        boolean finished = false;
        while (!finished) {
            Command command = parser.getCommand();
            finished = processCommand(command);
        }
        System.out.println("Thank you for playing.  Good bye.");
    }

    /**
     * Print out the opening message for the player.
     */
    private void printWelcome() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Welcome to the world of Zuul!");
        System.out.println("Zuul is a new, incredibly boring adventure game.");
        System.out.println("Type 'help' if you need help.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(getCurrentRoom().getLongDescription());
    }

    /**
     * Given a command, process (that is: execute) the command.
     * If this command ends the game, true is returned, otherwise false is
     * returned.
     */
    private boolean processCommand(Command command) {
        boolean wantToQuit = false;

        if (command.isUnknown()) {
            System.out.println("I don't know what you mean...");
            return false;
        }

        String commandWord = command.getCommandWord();
        if (commandWord.equals("help"))
            printHelp();
        else if (commandWord.equals("go"))
            goRoom(command);
        else if (commandWord.equals("quit")) {
            wantToQuit = quit(command);
        }
        return wantToQuit;
    }

    // implementations of user commands:

    /**
     * Print out some help information.
     * Here we print some stupid, cryptic message and a list of the 
     * command words.
     */
    private void printHelp() {
        System.out.println("You are lost. You are alone. You wander");
        System.out.println("around at the university.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your command words are:");
        parser.showCommands();
    }

    /** 
     * Try to go to one direction. If there is an exit, enter the new
     * room, otherwise print an error message.
     */
    private void goRoom(Command command) {
        if (!command.hasSecondWord()) {
            // if there is no second word, we don't know where to go...
            System.out.println("Go where?");
            return;
        }

        String direction = command.getSecondWord();

        // Try to leave current room.
        Room nextRoom = getCurrentRoom().getExit(direction);

        if (nextRoom == null)
            System.out.println("There is no door!");
        else {
            getCurrentRoom() = nextRoom;
            System.out.println(getCurrentRoom().getLongDescription());
        }
    }

    /** 
     * "Quit" was entered. Check the rest of the command to see
     * whether we really quit the game. Return true, if this command
     * quits the game, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean quit(Command command) {
        if (command.hasSecondWord()) {
            System.out.println("Quit what?");
            return false;
        } else
            return true; // signal that we want to quit
    }
}
```

This is the Player Class:

```
public class Player {
    private Room currentRoom;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Player
     */
    public Player() {
        currentRoom = getBeginRoom();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the current room that the player is in.
     */
    public void setCurrentRoom(Room room) {
        currentRoom = room;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current room that the player is in.
     */
    public Room getCurrentRoom() {
        return currentRoom;
    }
}
```

And here is the Scenario class:

```
public class Scenario {
    private List rooms; // List of all rooms in the game
    private Room beginRoom;
    private Random random;

    /**
     * Create a complete scenario (with all rooms).
     */
    public Scenario() {
        Room outside, theatre, pub, lab, office, transporter;

        // create the rooms
        outside = new Room("outside the main entrance of the university");
        theatre = new Room("in a lecture theatre");
        pub = new Room("in the campus pub");
        lab = new Room("in a computing lab");
        office = new Room("in the computing admin office");
        transporter = new TransporterRoom("in a dark place", this);

        // initialise room exits
        outside.setExit("east", theatre);
        outside.setExit("south", lab);
        outside.setExit("west", pub);

        theatre.setExit("west", outside);
        theatre.setExit("north", transporter);

        transporter.setExit("south", theatre);

        pub.setExit("east", outside);

        lab.setExit("north", outside);
        lab.setExit("east", office);

        office.setExit("west", lab);

        beginRoom = outside; // start game outside

        rooms = new ArrayList();
        rooms.add(outside);
        rooms.add(theatre);
        rooms.add(pub);
        rooms.add(lab);
        rooms.add(office);
        rooms.add(transporter);

        random = new Random();
    }

    /**
     * Return the room where players start the game.
     */
    public Room getBeginRoom() {
        return beginRoom;
    }

    /**
     * Return a random room in this game.
     */
    public Room getRandomRoom() {
        return (Room) rooms.get(random.nextInt(rooms.size()));
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Be specific with error message - at which part you getting that error?

Comment: Likely a classpath issue. How are you trying to compile?

Comment: You use `getBeginRoom()` in your player class, but it is defined in your Scenario class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Game` class is calling `getCurrentRoom` on itself (or a static method statically imported somewhere out of sight) rather than on an instance of Player.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your classpath has the path to each of these files!